# When I have a Javascript function include an external Javascript file, how can I make the function block until the external file is completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, blocking

Let me preface this by stating that this needs to be done in **pure, vanilla Javascript, with no 3rd-party libraries or frameworks** (**emphatically not JQuery**).

Say I have a JS file, named `included_script.js`, with the following content:

```
function sayIt() {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

Now say I have the following simplified JS function that loads the external JS file and attempts to execute the `sayIt` function defined therein:

```
function loadIt() {
    var externalScript = document.createElement("script");
    externalScript.type = "text/javascript";
    externalScript.src = "js/included_script.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(externalScript);

    /* BLOCK HERE, and do not continue until externalScript
    (included_script.js) has been completely loaded from the server
    and included into the document, so that the following execution of 'sayIt'
    actually works as expected. */

    sayIt();   /*I expect the "Hello!" alert here, but 'sayIt' is undefined (which
    I think - but am not 100% sure - is because this line is reached before
    externalScript (included_script.js) is fully downloaded from the server). */
}
```

Note that before appending `externalScript` to the head I have tried things like `externalScript.setAttribute("defer", "defer")`, `externalScript.setAttribute("async", "async")` (even though I know this is redundant), and et cetera.  Note also that callbacks are not feasible for use.

How can I make function `loadIt` block at the *"BLOCK HERE"* part shown above until `externalScript` `(included_script.js)` is **completely** downloaded to the client, so that the `sayIt` function defined in `externalScript` `(included_script.js)` actually works when called from function `loadIt`?

**UPDATE BASED ON BOBRODES' BRILLIANT, SIMPLE ANSWER:**

`included_script.js` still has the following content:

```
function sayIt() {
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

`loadIt` is now turned into a class (it's a lot more complex than this, but this shows the bare-bones mechanics required for it to work):

```
function loadIt() {
    this.loadExternal = async function() {
        return new Promise(
            function(resolve, reject) {
                try {
                    var externalScript = document.createElement("script");
                    externalScript.type = "text/javascript";
                    externalScript.src = "js/included_script.js";

                    if (externalScript.readyState) {
                        externalScript.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (externalScript.readyState == "loaded" ||
                                externalScript.readyState == "complete") {
                                externalScript.onreadystatechange = null;
                                resolve(true);
                            }
                        };
                    } else {
                        externalScript.onload = function() {
                            resolve(true);
                        };
                    }

                    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(externalScript);
                }
                catch(err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Now, in my main code, I can do the following, with it being guaranteed that function `sayIt` is loaded and ready for use before it's invoked.

*From inside an async function:*

```
var loader = new loadIt();
await loader.loadExternal();
sayIt();
```

*From outside an async function:*

```
var loader = new loadIt();

(async function() {
    await loader.loadExternal();
})().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});

sayIt();
```

This works beautifully -- exactly what I was after.  Thanks, Bob!

As a side note, I know there is a rampant and short-sighted *"blocking is always evil in every case imaginable, and can never, ever, under any circumstances, result in anything good"* mentality, but I disagree that blocking is bad when a heavily-data-driven GUI is being generated, which depends on multiple custom classes that, in-turn, depend on each other and/or other classes/resources/scripts -- especially when the rendered GUI elements have multiple event handlers (`onclick`, `oninput`, `onfocus`, etc.) that expect the existence/usability of instances of these classes and their methods.

Comment: in this simplistic case, `externalScript.onload = sayIt;` more complex case, `externalScript.addEventListener('load', function(e) { /* do things here */});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $.ready() - how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

Comment: The function `sayIt` is just actually a way of demonstrating that I want everything defined in `included_script.js` to be immediately available;  I may or may not be calling its resources immediately.  This will be a quasi dependency loader.  When I load a dependency, I want everything in it available to immediately following lines.  Some dependencies, and other things requiring them, will be dynamically loaded at run time, based on various logic.

Comment: Don't block... you'll be breaking all sorts of stuff.  Fix your code.

Comment: `based on various logic` - well, only you know this logic, so there's not much can be done for you

Comment: If you can't use callbacks, then use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which are designed to create a "blocking" mechanism in an asynchronous environment without having to add a separate callback function.

Comment: @BobRodes: Yes!  `await` [for a promise return] before moving on to the next line is perfect.  Please turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use callbacks, then use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which are designed to create a "blocking" mechanism in an asynchronous environment without having to add a separate callback function.

Comment: I literally smacked myself on the forehead when I read your answer.  Thanks for the help as well as the bruise.

Comment: @JohnDoe Nicely done, John. And thanks for posting your solution. You're very welcome.